# Skip stage if no commit occurred since last pipeline execution

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab repository which builds and runs all tests on a commit/merge. When creating a tag on the master branch I deploy the artifact on our nexus.

So here is what happens with my current ci configuration:

1. Merge a branch into master -> `build/test`
2. Tag merged master -> `build/test`, `deploy`

As you see the second `build/test` job is actually unnecessary in this case as no commit occurred between the merge and the tag.
Is there a way that I can configure a job conditional, if no change happened since the last pipeline execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a really good documentation on the GitLab pages: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified

Your solution would be to add this in your `build/test`:

```
except:
  - tags
```

Comment: Yes, your are right of course. I just figured that I was worried if a comit should happen in between. But this of course will initiate a build/test too anyway...